# The term 'C:\chefboot_win.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Tags: powershell

I have seen several similar messages but none of the suggestions I have read so far have solved my error. chefboot_win.psq is a script which I am trying to execute on a remote server like this -

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> icm {param($lanID,$passW) C:\chefboot_win.ps1 @PSBoundParameters} -ArgumentList "userid", "password" -cn 10.XX.XX.XXX -Credential administrator
```

This is the error I get after I enter the administrator password in the pop-up window.

```
The term 'C:\chefboot_win.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\chefboot_win.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
+ PSComputerName        : 10.XX.XX.XXX
```

The script runs fine when I do not use params and hardcode the values of $lanID and $passW in it. Can someone help with why this is not working? Thanks!

Comment: Does the file `C:\chefboot_win.ps1` exist on the host with the IP address 10.XX.XX.XXX?

Comment: Ansgar - no, it does not. I used to execute this command on my workstation (with -FilePath) but I had to hard code the $lanID and $passW in the script. Instead I want to pass the parameters. So I changed it to use -ArgumentList. I assumed the file can still be accessible to my workstation while the script executed remotely. It seems like if I want to use -ArgumentList, I have to make the script file accessible to the remote server?

Comment: Well, the lack of file is what causes the error you observed. How do you expect to run a local script on a remote host, if that script isn't present on the remote host? It doesn't magically copy itself there just because you call it. Parameters passed via `-ArgumentList` don't have anything to do with this problem. At all.

Comment: Ansgar - this is how I used to run a local script on a remote host and it worked well - 
'icm -cn 10.XX.XX.XXX -Credential administrator -FilePath C:\chefboot_win.ps1'

Answer (score 1):

You can execute other scripts with this syntax:

```
.\MyScript.ps1
```

or, alternatively, if you have absolute full path:

```
& "C:\location of my Script.ps1"
```

Comment: Erti - the syntax of the file path was not the issue. As Ansgar has pointed out, the issue was the location of the script file. Apparently, when using the -FilePath switch, local file is acceptable but when -ArgumentList switch is used, the file has to be accessible from the remote host. This is unfortunate because now I have to somehow make the script accessible to the remote server to run the script with params. Thanks for responding.